# Set JAVA_HOME to be the root of java installation

Tags: java, hadoop, java-home

I'm currently using hadoop and in the config part there's 
"define JAVA_HOME at least to be the root of your java installation"
I'm actually confused about it.
Say, my JAVA_HOME when using: `echo $JAVA_HOME` is: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

and my java installation when using: which java is:
`/usr/bin/java`

What change should I make to set JAVA_HOME as the java root?

Thanks!

And for a follow up, I think the tutorial mentioned to make the change inside the conf/en-sh part.
I tried the combinations of the below answers proposed, but still got the error of 
1. invalid identifier for the export JAVA_HOME = .. part
2. unable to load hadoop library

Please help.....
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, I have JAVA_HOME set to `/Library/Java/Home` on Mountain Lion. Fair enough... add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` line to the .bash_profile, .zshrc file in your home directory. If you're using tcsh, the line you want is `setenv JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/Home`. The default shell on recent versions of OS X for users in bash. You can find out what you're using using `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: OP's asking *what* to do in order to make the change, means what steps and how i assume ... your answer does not provide anything helpful. If are using Mac and you know the steps please provide it. Thanks

Comment: the tutorial said "to edit the conf/hadoop-env.sh" in this case, should I just do: export JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/Home?

Comment: @user2209904: yes, but omit all space characters, especially around `=`. The format should be `export VAR=value`.

Answer (score 1):

For GNU/Linux operation system users: in your bash profile set your Java Home variable `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java` then 
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/java`.
[Here](http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/2012/08/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-and-path-in-linux/) is the complete tutorial.

Comment: Your link is for Linux, OPs paths are found on the Macintosh. If that wasn't enough, the PATH variable is for directories, not files.

Comment: You're right about the path, `/usr/bin/java` tricked me. But I think thats the way I have changed my JAVA_HOME in linux.

Comment: Correct your path. I still expect your answer to be voted down, though.

Answer (score 0):

Set you JAVA_HOME to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk. That's enough.

Comment: ... Until the JDK is updated, at which point your solution breaks.